# MAUI Show/Hide controls based on mode New/Edit/View

Tags: controls, show-hide, maui

I need an idea, please. I have a Details form which shows the fields of a model (about 10 fields in all). There are three modes in which I could show this view - in mode "Edit", in mode "New" (which, of course, is like an edit but without values), and in mode "View" (no changes allowed, just labels).

I could of course create three Details pages, one for each mode, and call them selectively, but I would like to have just one and pass the "DocumentMode" parameter to it. That View should bind to that mode and selectively show/hide controls, probably like "DocumentMode = VIEW => Show labels" or "DocumentMode = EDIT => Show Entry or Editor, show DatePicker, TimePicker, etc".

My question is this: How do I show/hide these groups of controls depending on the DocumentMode parameter ? Which would be the best way to do this ? I could probably bind the "IsVisible" property to my documentMode parameter, but I think that is a really ugly solution (and I assume that regardless of whether the controls are used or not in a specific mode, they will all be loaded anyway).

Thank you.
Alex

Comment: If you have any ideas please feel free to post it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a `Listview` or `Collectionview` to represent your data because you mentioned that you have 10 fields.

In addition, you said you need a "new" button, so you can set it at the top of the app as a button, when you click the button then you jump to another page which is blank and you can add the data.
This must refer to the `shell` you may need to set a navigation.

Then the "view" and the "edit" you can use the property `SelectionChanged` to control the item, I mean when you click the item in collectionview, the `SelectionChanged` method can be triggered and turn to another page which can show the detail about the item you clicked. In the page you can view and edit the data.

Here are some articles you might be able to use: [Listview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/listview), [Collectionview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/), [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation)

If you have more information to add, please kindly share with me.